# This program using wxpython don't run

Tags: python, wxpython

This program is that wx.textctrl is written "clicked" when button is clicked.

It don't run.

```
import wx

class Mainwindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(300, 300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'OK', size=(70, 30))
        button = Click_btn()
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, button.click_btn)
        hbox1.Add(btn, 0)
        vbox.Add(hbox1, 0)

        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
        self.tc = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        hbox2.Add(self.tc, 1, wx.EXPAND) 
        vbox.Add(hbox2, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        panel.SetSizer(vbox)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

class Click_btn(Mainwindow):
    def click_btn(self, event):
        Mainwindow.tc.WriteText("clicked\n")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    Mainwindow(None, -1, u"sample")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Error panel disapper immediately.

Maybe Click_btn class is wrong.

Where should I change?

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up several concepts in your code:

- `Click_btn` should probably not derive from `MainWindow`, but from `wx.Button`.
- `click_btn` should not access `MainWindow` but an instance of `MainWindow`.
- The simplest solution would be to implement the event handler as method of `MainWindow` and to bind that one to the button.

I would propose to read http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started and http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/index.html and then give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

Your Click_btn class is a subclass of your Mainwindow class, which takes 3 arguments to **init**, along with itself. When you create a new Click_btn, you're not passing in any arguments.

Having click_btn in its own class doesn't really make sense; move it to the Mainwindow class. The following should work:

```
import wx

class Mainwindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(300, 300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'OK', size=(70, 30))
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.click_btn)
        hbox1.Add(btn, 0)
        vbox.Add(hbox1, 0)

        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
        self.tc = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        hbox2.Add(self.tc, 1, wx.EXPAND) 
        vbox.Add(hbox2, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        panel.SetSizer(vbox)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def click_btn(self, event):
        self.tc.WriteText("clicked\n")


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    Mainwindow(None, -1, u"sample")
    app.MainLoop()
```